# Transparent Color Effect Over the Image Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

I am working on an Image editor android app like : [BeFunkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.befunky.BeFunkyPhotoEditor&hl=en)
 I have achieved many effects like this android app but still some effects are been headache for me. Like PopArt Effect. Please see below images. One is original and second is popart colored effect :

Original ::

[image]

PopArt ::

[image]

I have used RGB Color Matrix To get color effect on bitmap. But When i use it worked like one color in whole image but here in this effect there are multiple colors on the image. If anybody here who can guide me please tell me how can i achieve this color effect. Thank you for your time.

Following Code I am using for color Effects ::

```
    public static final float[] float_color_matrix = new float[] { 2.6f, 0, 0.1f, 0, 0, 0.1f, 1.2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(float_color_matrix));
    ColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);

    imageView.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

Comment: please post the code on how you are applying the effect.

Comment: @Neil...Please see post i have updated it with code...

Comment: You also need to show your float_color_matrix array please. That is what I wanted to see

Comment: // // Image 2
 public static final float[] float_color_matrix = new float[] {

 2.6f, 0, 0.1f, 0, 0,

 0.1f, 1.2f, 0, 0, 0,

 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use a ColorFilter to achieve this effect

Comment: That is my question, how can i achieve this effect on bitmap ?

Comment: Check my answer. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code should do the trick. I came pretty close to the result you're looking for. If it's not exactly the same you can just play around with the colors in the `colors` array. I use [this](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) nifty tool to find hex color codes.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param yourDrawableResource (ex R.drawable.ic_drawable)
 * @return the image bitmap with the correct overlay
 */
public static Bitmap setPopArtGradient(Context context, int yourDrawableResource) {
    int[] colors = new int[]{Color.parseColor("#FFD900"),Color.parseColor("#FF5300"),
                             Color.parseColor("#FF0D00"),Color.parseColor("#AD009F"),
                             Color.parseColor("#1924B1")};
    float[] colorPositions = new float[]{0.2f,0.4f,0.6f,0.8f,1.0f};

    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(yourDrawableResource);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    /* Create your gradient. */
    LinearGradient grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.getHeight(), colors, colorPositions, TileMode.CLAMP);

    /* Draw your gradient to the top of your bitmap. */
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    p.setAlpha(110); //adjust alpha for overlay intensity
    p.setShader(grad);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), p);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Then you just implement it by doing this

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(setPopArtGradient(yourContext, R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

If you want to pass a bitmap you can do this.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param bmp (your bitmap)
 * @return the image bitmap with the correct overlay
 */
public static Bitmap setPopArtGradientFromBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    int[] co = new int[]{Color.parseColor("#FFD900"),Color.parseColor("#FF5300"),Color.parseColor("#FF0D00"),Color.parseColor("#AD009F"),Color.parseColor("#1924B1")};
    float[] coP = new float[]{0.2f,0.4f,0.6f,0.8f,1.0f};

    Bitmap bitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    /* Create your gradient. */
    LinearGradient grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.getHeight(), co, coP, TileMode.CLAMP);

    /* Draw your gradient to the top of your bitmap. */
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    p.setAlpha(110);
    p.setShader(grad);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), p);

    return bitmap;
}
```

I applied it to one of my Photos I took and this was the result

[image: edited photo]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello Bro i want to pass Bitmap than int yourDrawableResource, so what change i have to do....???